# Illegal constrain error when flipping back to tableView after reloadData

Tags: ios, autolayout

This one is really freaking weird. Here's the error:

***** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal. constraint: view:>'**

So my custom cell has a subview, that I is added in the configuration step. That is, I deuque a cell, then configure it with a data object. In the configuration step, it adds the third party subview if it doesn't exist:

```
if (!self.thirdPartyAnswerView) {
    self.thirdPartyAnswerView = [TCThirdPartyAPIHelper thirdPartyAnswerViewForThirdPartyAPIServiceType:answer.thirdPartyObject.thirdPartyAPIType];
    self.thirdPartyAnswerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.contentWrapperView addSubview:self.thirdPartyAnswerView];
    NSDictionary *metrics = @{
                              @"TC_CELL_TOP_PADDING": [NSNumber numberWithFloat:TC_CELL_TOP_PADDING],
                              @"TC_CELL_BOTTOM_PADDING": [NSNumber numberWithFloat:TC_CELL_BOTTOM_PADDING],
                              @"TC_CELL_RIGHT_PADDING": [NSNumber numberWithFloat:TC_CELL_RIGHT_PADDING],
                              @"TC_CELL_LEFT_PADDING": [NSNumber numberWithFloat:TC_CELL_LEFT_PADDING],
                              };
    [self.contentWrapperView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-TC_CELL_LEFT_PADDING-[_thirdPartyAnswerView]-TC_CELL_RIGHT_PADDING-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_thirdPartyAnswerView)]];
    [self.contentWrapperView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-TC_CELL_TOP_PADDING-[_thirdPartyAnswerView]-TC_CELL_BOTTOM_PADDING-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_thirdPartyAnswerView)]];
}
```

This all works fine. In fact, it works great. I step into my answer cells (which presents a modal edit/creation flow), and then finish and come back to the same screen. I update the rows nicely with animations instead of calling `reloadData`.

[image: Screen]

The problem comes in when I hit the category button after I have existing data. It pulls up a category selection modal. When I choose a category, it calls `reloadData` in the previous screen, and then animates the category modal away. Well, at least that's what it's supposed to do. **Instead it crashes immediately at the start of the animation. It calls `reloadData` without a problem, but as soon as the animation starts, boom.** It either throws the crash I showed above, doesn't provide any explanation, or crashes with the complaint of `_supportsContentDimensionVariables` selector being sent to the wrong object.

Since the view used can vary between cells, in the call `prepareForReuse` I remove the `thirdPartyAnswerView`. If I remove this, it doesn't crash (but then I have a view in my cell I don't want). I tried removing the constraints before and after:

```
if (self.thirdPartyAnswerView) {
    [self.contentWrapperView removeConstraints:self.thirdPartyAnswerView.constraints];
    [self.thirdPartyAnswerView removeFromSuperview];
    self.thirdPartyAnswerView = nil;
}
```

That didn't work. I tried moving this stuff out of `prepareForReuse` and into the configuration section (remove the subview before adding a new one). That didn't work. I'm at a loss.

### Update

Here is the code called when a category in the modal is chosen:

```
categorySelectionVC.didTouchCategoryBlock = ^(TCCategory *category) {
    TCQuestionBuilderViewController *sself = weakself;
    sself.category = category;
    [sself.tableView reloadData];
    [sself.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:TableSectionCategory] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    [sself dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
};
```

<strike>What I've since determined, is that if I comment out the `selectRowAtIndexPath` bit after the reload, it works properly. What I don't understand is why. I've used this many times. I reloadData, reselect what was selected so that it animates "off" when the tableView is seen again.</strike>

**I was incorrect. While removing that did solve it initially, if you entered the modal again and then selected a category again it crashed.**

## SOLVED

Thanks to sapi, I figured out that constraints weren't being removed properly. Using the `constraints` property off of `thirdPartyView` doesn't include the constraints stored on a parent view. Had to use this syntax, although I'm guessing there's a shorter way of doing this:

```
for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.contentWrapperView.constraints) {
    if (constraint.firstItem == self.thirdPartyAnswerView || constraint.secondItem == self.thirdPartyAnswerView) {
        [constraints addObject:constraint];
    }
}
[self.contentWrapperView removeConstraints:constraints];
```

Comment: In the configuration step, have you verified through lldb that (a) the `contentWrapperView` doesn't have a subview of type `TCThirdPartyAPIHelper` and (b) that it doesn't have any unexpected constraints?  Since the `!self.thirdPartyAnswerView` check doesn't test this directly, my first thought is that unintended/old constraints might be slipping through the cracks.

Comment: Good catch. It does somehow have unexpected constraints, remnants of before it was prepared for reuse. So.. am I removing constraints incorrectly?

Comment: I don't have Xcode handy to check your syntax, but check that if you step past the `[self.contentWrapperView removeConstraints:]` line, everything gets removed as expected? (I can't remember offhand if reverse constraints have the same identity; if they don't, then that won't work, as A -> B (the constraint on the `contentWrapperView` referencing the `thirdPartyAnswerView`) will be a different object to B -> A (the ones in `self.thirdPartyAnswerView.constraints`), so nothing will be removed)

Comment: You were right. Apparently my syntax didn't grab the correct constraints. Had to use the code above. Thanks for the point in the right direction! If you add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constraints are bi-directional, but the reverse relationship is represented by a different object to the forward relationship.

If you create a constraint using, for example:

```
[self.contentWrapperView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-TC_CELL_LEFT_PADDING-[_thirdPartyAnswerView]-TC_CELL_RIGHT_PADDING-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_thirdPartyAnswerView)]];
```

then `self.contentWrapperView` and `_thirdPartyAnswerView` both have constraints added to them, but while they both represent the same relationship, they are *different objects*.

When you call:

```
[self.contentWrapperView removeConstraints:self.thirdPartyAnswerView.constraints];
```

this attempts to remove all constraints on `self.contentWrapperView` which are *identical* to those on `self.thirdPartyAnswerView`, ie none.

To remove the appropriate constraints, you have to loop through the array and identify those referring to the `thirdPartyAnswerView` (see edit to question for one way of doing this).

Comment: Thanks again. Spent hours on that one.

Comment: No worries.  Constraints have a habit of doing that to people - me included :)